# Split List in tcl based on members

Tags: list, split, tcl

Is it possible to split a List in 20:30 members in tcl?
Given A list having 50 members, I want to split it in 20:30 and at the same time want to categorize the values it is receiving via args.

Comment: Clarifying would help us answer. Please edit your question to give an example (preferably short) of what you want to take as input and get as output.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, use

```
set out [list [lrange $in 0 19] [lrange $in 20 end]]
```

I do not understand that "at the same time want to categorize the values it is receiving via args" bit. Try to elaborate on it.